# Case fans: on PSU or SYS-FAN splitter?

Tags: case, cooling

A week ago I built my new pc. The case came with 2 in-built 3-pin case fans, and my motherboard only has one 3-pin SYS-FAN connection. One case fan is in top-rear of the case, and the other fan at the bottom-front.

Currently I'm using only the rear-top fan and I do not have problems with heat or airflow. However, I'd like to connect an additional fan, just because I have it.

There are two possibilities for the fan on the front:

1. I can connect it directly to the PSU with a cable like [this](https://www.onlinekabelshop.nl/molex-4x-3p-fan-kabel-2x-5v-2x-12v-0-30-meter-29256). The con is that the fan will always rotate at full speed. I do not know if fans are used to rotate at full speed.
2. I can connect it with a Y-cable like [this](https://www.conrad.nl/nl/pc-ventilator-y-kabel-2x-pc-ventilator-stekker-4-polig-1x-pc-ventilator-bus-4-polig-015-m-zwart-akasa-976189.html?WT.mc_id=gshop&insert=8J&gclid=CjwKEAjwq8y8BRCstYTm8qeT9mwSJACZGjUk2a1xX9Fc3CWUfkEBGVtNCVs1g_3KscjI1_6y-v6rzBoCWmfw_wcB&tid=211354628_17335160228_pla-218016956228_pla-976189&WT.srch=1) or [this](https://www.onlinekabelshop.nl/3-pins-case-fan-v-2x-3-pins-case-fan-m-splitter-0-10-meter?id=OKS-54617&gclid=CjwKEAjwq8y8BRCstYTm8qeT9mwSJACZGjUkr17KTjFtrkey2eHO3H-yGnBBe4rJksTGp5gJFBfVjBoCHqzw_wcB). Will a splitter like that work well? Looking at the second link, it seems that the speed-controlling cable is missing. Is this also the case in the first one?

I do not want to use a fan controller.

What do you recommend?

Comment: @ArtOfCode This question is a pre-purchase recommendation question and therefore can impossibly be flagged as "troubleshooting hardware". I'm asking what part I should buy and why.

Comment: "Is it okay for a fan to spin at full? Will a splitter work? Does this cable have the right part?" Those seem to be your main questions, and are why I closed it. Pre purchase questions are incredibly difficult to get tight, and we've considered dropping them entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just connect it to the PSU unless the noise it makes is not acceptable. It is not bad for the fan to run at full speed all the time. The splitters will communicate the same fan speed to both fans.